# EF Query Help - Grouping and Sub queries

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have data table (DOCs, which is the DBSet in my context) with below data

```
ID   Code   Rev
1    A1     1
2    A1     2
3    A1     3
4    A3     1
5    A2     1
6    A2     2
```

I need to select the records which has a records for each Code which has the highest Rev. My expected result is

```
ID   Code   Rev
3    A1     3
6    A2     2
4    A3     1
```

The ID column is the PK of the table and Code+Rev is unique.
Note: There are other fields in the table which i need to get for the result. Ideal would be to get a iqueryable (Doc is the model class), i was think of selecting the ID within an inner query and then use that to get the iqueryable of docs.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var res = from r in DOCs
          where (from c in DOCs
                 group c by c.Code into g
                 select new {
                    localCode = g.Key,
                    localRev = g.Max(t => t.Rev)
                 }).Any(x => x.localCode == r.Code && x.localRev == r.Rev)
          select r;
```

`res` is IQueryable.